# SVG image does not appear, no errors

Tags: flutter

I wanna show the svg in a `container`, the container colours does show as `grey` but the vector image does not appear. No errors are being produced. I have added the dependancy `flutter_svg: ^0.22.0` and

**Svg image:** this is placed at `/Assets/Vector.svg`

```
<svg width="25" height="26" viewBox="0 0 25 26" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M4.9435 8.38116H0.706215C0.282486 8.38116 0 8.62978 0 9.00271V25.1629C0 25.5359 0.282486 25.7845 0.706215 25.7845H4.9435C5.36723 25.7845 5.64972 25.5359 5.64972 25.1629V9.00271C5.64972 8.62978 5.36723 8.38116 4.9435 8.38116Z" fill="white"/> </svg>
```

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: SvgPicture.asset('/Assets/Vector.svg',
              color: Colors.black))
```

[image]

the small black line is the svg (appears in my browser)
[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the page from your emulator or device

Comment: @JideGuru added

Comment: can you share a screenshot to the svg image, cause I tried your svg code and nothing shown!

Comment: @AL.Sharie added, it's a one black line for the testing purposes. The above mentioned svg data draws it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the file path in your .yaml file? Is it */Assets/Vector.svg* ? Because normally if you have only assets folder & no more sub-folder inside.

You should use the path *'Assets/Vector.svg'* in your case.

[image: Accessing Asset Folder]

[image]

In this case, my path is

> child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/login.svg')

Comment: yaml file is alright it seems, it includes the parent folder under `assets`

Comment: you should follow the file path declared in the .yaml file.

Comment: Or maybe you can show the assets folder & also the .yaml file where the assets are declared

Comment: @phill D: Already did, once I put `/` it gives me options to select the entire path, and I have used full path so the path is accurate as I see.

Comment: finally it works, it needed to include the `lib` folder as well, it's strange as it didn't produce any error saying the asset cannot be found or something than just not showing anything. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to build the app all over again. Flutter clean to be precise. Some packeges requires a full rebuild including flutter_svg.

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml assets section ? 
Another question is are you having any errors in the debug console?

Answer (score 0):

try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`, sometime cache causes crazy stuff